# php mysql ORDER BY not working ... tried looking at others, they aren't having the same issue

Tags: php, mysql

please help ... i'm pretty knowledgeable when it comes to php mysql, but for some reason i can't figure this out.

i have this query:

```
$get_points = "SELECT user_id, accum_points FROM total_points ORDER BY accum_points DESC"; 
$run_points = mysqli_query($con, $get_points); 
while($row_points = mysqli_fetch_array($run_points)) {

other stuff in here 

}
```

and here's what is currently in the db

```
points_id  |  user_id  | accum_points
_____________________________________

   31           12           211.2
   32           13            7.4
   33            1           10.4
```

but it spits out it in the order of 7.4, 211.2, 10.4. i don't understand what is going on with this ... i've looked at a lot of the other questions asked about ORDER BY not working ... can anybody help?

thanks!

Comment: It is sorted as a string. "7.4" > "211.2"  > "10.4". Is your column declared as a float or int ? If not, you will have to use a mysql fonction in the order by...

Comment: you have to cast the column as a numeric value.

Comment: holy f**king s**t ... i went through so quickly when i was making the db that i made it a varchar ... so now i feel like a moron ... thank you ... changed it to a float and it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made the mistake of making the column a varchar ... so that was stupid of me ... sorry about this guys